# Cannot deploy Service Fabric application to dev/local cluster

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric

VS 2017, attempting to deploy an application to my local/dev Service Fabric cluster, I get this message:

> The active solution configuration is not configured to build or deploy the Service Fabric Application project.  This can happen if the solution configuration is not configured to build/deploy the x64 platform which this project requires.  An attempt will be made to debug launch the project.  The application on the cluster, if it exists, may not be up-to-date with the source code since the project was not built and deployed. Do you want to continue?

This asks the same question, but none of the proposed solutions work for me: 
[The active solution configuration is not configured to build or deploy the Service Fabric Application Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118175/the-active-solution-configuration-is-not-configured-to-build-or-deploy-the-servi?rq=1)

My solution config is:[image]

- ClientLib isn't deployed
- Fabric is the actual SF application
- The last two are a WebApi and a stateless service, respectively.

In addition, I've gone back to all other libraries (pulled in as Nuget packages), changed them to x64, redeployed, and updated this SF solution to the latest.

Still get the prompt. Any suggestions on what other solutions to explore?

Initially, the site would push to the cluster and hit breakpoints. It seems to have regressed and won't push the application at all.

Comment: Did you configure OptOutLinks.Fabric as the 'startup project' in your solution?

Comment: @LoekD I did...that was one of the three proposed solutions in the linked question. Unfortunately, it had no effect...

Comment: Can you check the 'Build' checkbox for **OptOutLinks.Fabric** project?

Comment: @OlegKarasik so, I did as you suggested and it worked. if you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as such. I can only assume it got unchecked as I was making my way through various fixes. Now, I'm wondering what the original issue was, since I apparently fixed it along the way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this  [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303512/cannot-deploy-service-fabric-application-to-dev-local-cluster#comment91676525_52303512) as answer.

---

Can you check the 'Build' checkbox for **OptOutLinks.Fabric** project?